# [CPTPlotRange objCType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I'm trying to implement the real-time plot example from core-plot into my ios project, I keep getting `[CPTPlotRange objCType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` which seems to be stopping the CPTAnimation for moving the graph to the newest values.

This is pretty much all of my code, and I cannot figure out why this issue occurs

```
-(id)initWithGraphView:(CPTGraphHostingView *) gView name:(NSString *)label {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        _graphView = gView;
        CGRect bounds = _graphView.bounds;
        _graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
        _graphView.hostedGraph = _graph;
        _currentIndex = 0;
        _plotData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:kMaxDataPoints];
        [_plotData removeAllObjects];


        CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
        majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.75;
        majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor colorWithGenericGray:CPTFloat(0.2)] colorWithAlphaComponent:CPTFloat(0.75)];

        CPTMutableLineStyle *minorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
        minorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.25;
        minorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:CPTFloat(0.1)];

        // Axes
        // X axis
        CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)_graph.axisSet;
        CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
        x.labelingPolicy        = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
        x.orthogonalPosition    = @0.0;
        x.majorGridLineStyle    = majorGridLineStyle;
        x.minorGridLineStyle    = minorGridLineStyle;
        x.minorTicksPerInterval = 9;
        x.title                 = @"X Axis";

        NSNumberFormatter *labelFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        labelFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterNoStyle;
        x.labelFormatter           = labelFormatter;

        // Y axis
        CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
        y.labelingPolicy        = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
        y.orthogonalPosition    = @0.0;
        y.majorGridLineStyle    = majorGridLineStyle;
        y.minorGridLineStyle    = minorGridLineStyle;
        y.minorTicksPerInterval = 3;
        y.title                 = @"Y Axis";
        y.axisConstraints       = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];

        // Rotate the labels by 45 degrees, just to show it can be done.
        x.labelRotation = CPTFloat(M_PI_4);

        // Create the plot
        CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
        dataSourceLinePlot.identifier     = kPlotIdentifier;
        dataSourceLinePlot.cachePrecision = CPTPlotCachePrecisionDouble;
        dataSourceLinePlot.interpolation = CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved;

        CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
        lineStyle.lineWidth              = 3.0;
        lineStyle.lineColor              = [CPTColor greenColor];
        dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;

        dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
        [_graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];

        // Plot space
        CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)_graph.defaultPlotSpace;
        plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@0.0 length:@(kMaxDataPoints - 2)];
        plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@0.0 length:@1000000.0];

    }

    return self;
}

-(void)newData:(int)value
{
    NSLog(@"adding, %i", value);
    CPTGraph *theGraph = _graph;
    CPTPlot *thePlot   = [theGraph plotWithIdentifier:kPlotIdentifier];

    if ( thePlot ) {
        if ( self.plotData.count >= kMaxDataPoints ) {
            [self.plotData removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            [thePlot deleteDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
        }

        CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)_graph.defaultPlotSpace;
        NSUInteger location       = (self.currentIndex >= kMaxDataPoints ? self.currentIndex - kMaxDataPoints + 2 : 0);

        CPTPlotRange *oldRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@( (location > 0) ? (location - 1) : 0 )
                                                              length:@(kMaxDataPoints - 2)];
        CPTPlotRange *newRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(location)
                                                              length:@(kMaxDataPoints - 2)];

        [CPTAnimation animate:plotSpace
                     property:@"xRange"
                fromPlotRange:oldRange
                  toPlotRange:newRange
                     duration:CPTFloat(1.0 / kFrameRate)];

        self.currentIndex++;
        [self.plotData addObject:@(value)];
        [thePlot insertDataAtIndex:self.plotData.count - 1 numberOfRecords:1];
    }
}

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(nonnull CPTPlot *)plot
{
    return _plotData.count;
}

-(nullable id)numberForPlot:(nonnull CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSNumber *num = nil;

    switch ( fieldEnum ) {
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
            num = @(index + _currentIndex - _plotData.count);
            break;

        case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
            num = _plotData[index];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return num;
}
```

Comment: What line does it crash on?

Comment: It doesn't crash, it keeps sending the unrecognized selector error after the amount of data reaches kMaxDataPoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in Core Plot 2.1 that caused this error when animating plot ranges. It's fixed on the master branch and will be in the next release.

In the meantime, you can pull the latest code from [GitHub](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) or point Cocoapods to the latest code on `master` rather than to a release package (`pod 'CorePlot', :git => 'https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot.git'`).